# Majorana fermions - Scattering amplitude/Feynman rules

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, scattering-cross-section, majorana-fermions

I am looking at 4 field scattering processes ($\phi \phi \rightarrow \psi \psi$) given by the Lagrangian is

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L}_i \supset \frac{\lambda_s}{\Lambda} \overline{ \psi} \psi |\phi|^2+ \frac{\lambda_a}{\Lambda} \overline{ \psi}\gamma_5 \psi |\phi|^2  
\end{equation}
and it is straightforward to write the scattering matrix for the case of a Dirac fermion being

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{M}_s = \frac{\lambda_s}{\Lambda} \overline u_s  (p)  v_{s'} (q) 
\end{equation}
and

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{M}_a = i \frac{\lambda_a}{\Lambda} \overline u_s  (p) \gamma_5 v_{s'} (q) 
\end{equation}
and I would like to know how this changes in the case of a Majorana field. I think both interactions are allowed since are both $C$ invariant but I don't see how knowing that the Majorana field has the constraint $\psi^c=\psi$ can change the result.

I think what I am missing is how to write the external legs for a Majorana fermion, do you have any suggestions? Or any references that you could to recommend?

Comment: The second term $\frac{\lambda_a}{\Lambda} \overline{ \psi}\gamma_5 \psi |\phi|^2$ in your Lagrangian is wrong, since it's not Hermitian. It should be $\frac{\lambda_a}{\Lambda} \overline{ \psi}i\gamma_5 \psi |\phi|^2$

Comment: Yes you're right, I forgot the $ i$, I'll edit that